# операции по модулю простого числа

Tags: математика

операции по модулю простого числа  +, +=, -, -=, =, ==, !=, >, <, >=, <=, *, *=, /, /=

опишите пожалуйста эти операции которые мне необходимо сделать через перегрузку операторов, если не трудно с примерами.

Comment: Сравнение типа больше/меньше в модулярной арифметике лишено смысла.

Comment: как я понял данные действия используются в криптографии. например сложение и вычитание это чтото вроде (a+b)%2^32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу описания и смысла операций, вам лучше проконсультироваться с любой книжкой по высшей алгебре. Эта часть вопроса лежит вне тематики нашего сайта. Можно начать, например, с [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E).

По поводу представления данных: чтобы избежать проблем, связанных с переполнением (и связанной с этим арифметикой по модулю 2 в степени размера слова), лучше всего для операций пользоваться более длинным типом, который гарантировано вмещает результат умножения. Для хранения значения можно использовать каноническое представление числа.

Получаем что-то вроде такого (С++):

```
template<unsigned int p>
class Residue
{
    typedef unsigned int working_type;
    typedef signed int diff_type;
    typedef unsigned long operation_type;
    static_assert(sizeof(operation_type) >= 2 * sizeof(working_type));
    static_assert(p > 1);

    working_type value;

    static working_type reduce(operation_type value)
    {
        operation_type residue = value % p;
        assert(0 <= residue && residue < p);
        // поскольку residue < p, приведение типов безопасно
        return (working_type)residue;
    }

    static working_type reduce(diff_type value)
    {
        // нам нужен более широкий тип, чтобы сложение с `p` было безопасно
        operation_type residue = value % p;
        operation_type residue = (remainder < 0) ? (remainder + p) : remainder;
        assert(0 <= residue && residue < p);
        // поскольку residue < p, приведение типов безопасно
        return (working_type)residue;
    }

    Residue(operation_type v) : value(reduce(v)) { }

public:
    Residue(working_type v) : value(reduce((operation_type)v)) { }
    Residue(diff_type v) : value(reduce(v)) { }

    Residue<p> operator + (const Residue<p>& other)
    {
        // здесь не может быть переполнения
        auto sum = (operation_type)value + (operation_type)other.value;
        return Residue<p>(sum);
    }

    // остальные методы более-менее аналогичны
};
```

Следите за возможным переполнением, оно может испортить результат! Протестируйте для больших значений `p`.

---

Обратите внимание, что если вам нужны операции по модулю `2^32`, вы можете просто воспользоваться обычной арифметикой на `uint32_t`, лишние биты отбрасываются автоматически. Кроме деления, с которым придётся [вспомнить алгоритм Евклида](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). (Знаковый тип **не подходит**, переполнение на нём есть undefined behaviour!) Но это не вписывается в вашу задачу, так как степени двойки (вышей первой) не являются простыми числами.

Comment: [Статью про p-адические числа в догонку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-адическое_число)